# Improve VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below script which enters the following formula into range A2:A100.

```
WBNAME3 = "=IF(AND('\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\DIPS\Change Control\[Justice League.xlsm]iForms'!A2<>"""",    '\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\DIPS\Change Control\[Justice League.xlsm]iForms'!E2=""""),'\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\DIPS\Change Control\[Justice League.xlsm]iForms'!A2,"""")"
Worksheets("All Release Items").Range("E2:E100").Value = WBNAME3
```

I'm trying to define the following variable to shorten the script yet having no luck.

```
Justice = "=IF(AND('\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\DIPS\Change Control\[Justice League.xlsm]"
```

Please can someone help and show me where i'm going wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve; if not, please let me know.

```
Justice = "'\\insurance\it\FileData\Computers\DIPS\Change Control\[Justice League.xlsm]iForms'"

WBNAME3 = "=IF(AND(" & Justice & "!A2<>"""",  " & Justice & "!E2=""""),!" & Justice & "!A2,"""")"
Worksheets("All Release Items").Range("E2:E100").Formula= WBNAME3
```